# How to unit test when object is called within a wrapper using sinon?

Tags: javascript, sinon

The following "set" method needs to be tested using sinon, and I am not sure of how to do it.

```
// foo is just a wrapper
function Foo() {
  this.bar = new Bar();
}

Foo.prototype.set = function(x) {
   this.bar.set(x);
}
```

Here is an attempt to unit test it:

```
var foo = new Foo();
it("can called set method", function() {
  foo.set(x);
  foo.bar.set.calledOnceWith(x);
});
```

foo.bar.set.calledOnceWith is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.

You just need to create the `spy` on `Bar.prototype.set`:

```
import * as sinon from 'sinon';

function Bar() { }
Bar.prototype.set = function(x) {
  console.log(`Bar.prototype.set() called with ${x}`);
}

function Foo() {
  this.bar = new Bar();
}
Foo.prototype.set = function(x) {
  this.bar.set(x);
}

it('calls set on its instance of Bar', () => {
  const spy = sinon.spy(Bar.prototype, 'set');  // spy on Bar.prototype.set
  const foo = new Foo();
  foo.set(5);
  sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(spy, 5);  // SUCCESS
})
```